# How to drag and drop the Blazor component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How to drag and drop the Blazor component?

I have tried more cases so unable to achieve them. Any possibilities

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement drag and drop in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425677/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-blazor)

Comment: I am using drag and drop, no problem. [this is a sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64944487/14132160)

Answer (score 1):

Drag n Drop did not make the cut for 5.0 but they did make a sort of working version for Blazor here. The work in progress is here (it is on the roadmap for 6.0):
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commits/t-mabuc/drag-and-drop

The team based their design partially on this library:
https://github.com/Postlagerkarte/blazor-dragdrop

Answer (score 1):

There is working version - https://chrissainty.com/investigating-drag-and-drop-with-blazor/

I used this in my project

Answer (score -1):

You can use this NuGet package — https://www.nuget.org/packages/DragulaDropula

It's all about dragging and dropping components with the mouse cursor in Blazor. (Without JavaScript :))

Actually, in Blazor you can use drag html-events. But this library helps you handle positions of components right in C#, it also helps validate items which user drops to special areas. You can read the docs on [GitHub](https://github.com/marat0n/DragulaDropula).

Comment: It's not required.  Blazor exposes drag events on all objects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).